Get the download status of the plugin file file-saver in React
In React, I use the file-saver plugin to download PDF and it works well for me. But I want to get the state or status of the download process, so that I can change the text on the download button. Here is the import of the plugin:
import { saveAs } from "file-saver";

This is initialization:
const GetPDF = async (event) => {
  event.preventDefault();
  const blob = await pdf(<DocumentPDF />).toBlob();
  saveAs(blob, "custom-court-tool.pdf");
}

But like I said above, I want to get the download status of the file to change the text for the download button, similar to this:
<button>{Downloading ? "In the process..." : "Download"}</button>

Downloading - is a conditional value for understanding what I want to get.
But how do I do this with the file-saver plugin?

Seems that the documentation doesn't explain how to do it, but you can make it using a "Download" react state to handle the download options, something like:
const [isDownloading, setIsDownloading] = useState(false);

And, in the GetPDF function handle the state change
const GetPDF = async (event) => {
  event.preventDefault();
  setIsDownloading(true);
  const blob = await pdf(<DocumentPDF />).toBlob();
  saveAs(blob, "custom-court-tool.pdf");
  setIsDownloading(false);
}

